# Solving $x^{3/2}+1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> What will be the value of $x$ in this equation?
> $$x^{3/2}+1=0$$

I am trying this question by shifting $1$ on the right hand side. So the above equation will become
$$x^{3/2}=-1$$
So, the final value of $x$ will be $1$.

But the fact is that $x=1$ doesn't satisfy the above equation because $1+1$ is equal to $2$, not $0$.

Kindly help me out with this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with [tag:linear-algebra]?

Comment: You probably will need complex numbers here.

Comment: What complex value is possible?

Comment: The topic is mainly of linear equations

Comment: I am unable to find the exact value of x in this equation.

Comment: For future reference, even if this were a linear equation (which it is not), linear equations don't generally fall under the topic of *linear algebra*. Read the descriptions of tags before using them.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be clear, you did these manipulations?

$x^{\frac{3}{2}}+1=0$

$x^{\frac{3}{2}}=-1$

And then squared both sides? That is where your problem arises. When you squared both sides, you “lost information” specifically that it is a negative $1$ on the right side, not positive $1$.

Here is how I would do this:

Let $u=x^\frac{1}{2}$

Our equation is now:

$u^3=-1$

So we need a cube root of $-1$. There are three, and the simplest one fails. The other two are complex, and are most simply expressed as:

$e^{i\pi/3}$ and $e^{-i\pi/3}$

Now the final step is to square both of these to turn our $u$ values into $x$ values.

Therefore, $x= \{e^{2i\pi/3},e^{-2i\pi/3}\}$

Comment: If the question is (x^5/2 )+1=0 then how I will solve?

Comment: You would need to find fifth roots of $-1$, and then square them.